# Multiple Proxies in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following code:

URL is "localhost:8080/ZTESTSMT"

```js
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var process = require('process');

var app = express();

app.use(cors())

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8080));

app.use("/ZTEST123", express.static(__dirname + '/ZTEST123/webapp'));
app.use("/ZTESTSMT", express.static(__dirname + '/ZTESTSMT/webapp'));

app.use(proxy('http://localhost:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/service1/$metadata?sap-client=001&sap-language=EN'));
 
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

app.all('/', function(request, response) {
    
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {}); 

setTimeout(function() {
  process.exit();
}, 1000000);
```

Now I want to use different proxy for each path.
`ztest123` and `ztestsmt`.
I found a lot of examples but nothing worked.

I thought of something like this:

```js
app.use("/ZTEST123", proxy('http://localhost:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/service1/$metadata?sap-client=001&sap-language=EN'));
app.use("/ZTESTSMT", proxy('http://localhost:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/service2/$metadata?sap-client=001&sap-language=EN'));
```

Comment: Well That Code looks like it would work But I would handle mine in the router to be more safe `router.use()`

Comment: Thanks Ogoh. You probably right regarding to here https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy. But for any reason it does not work. But when the code is ok,  I will find out.